# Focus a button and change the display of a div

Tags: html, css, button, focus

I want to `focus a button` and make a div change the display to `display:flex`

This is the code pen link to be easier.

https://codepen.io/Rvssco/pen/bGoERxY

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to make a rearrangement in `div` blocks: https://codepen.io/angelhearted/pen/wvrMjyE

1. Moved `menudrop` to `textBtn-wrap` div. So the second point would work
2. Use tilda selector: `.buttonMenu:focus ~ .menudrop { display: flex; }`
3. There was a typo in the last selector, "l" in "display" was missing.